# How does Tomcat/Spring Boot search for application.properties?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am taking over the maintenance of a Spring Boot application running on Tomcat. It serves the website via a `.war` file located at

`/opt/app/tomcat/current/webapps/myapp.war`

We have several instances running, and I cannot figure out how this loads the server-specific `application.properties` file. It is not in the folder with the .war file. I cannot find any environment variables referencing it. When I do `ps aux | grep tomcat` I do not see it specified in the command line options passed to Java. I suspect it's loading the file from the location

`/opt/app/myapp/application.properties`

but I am not certain. What other places can I look to find the setting specifying the location of this file?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Comment: http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-application-configuration

Comment: Thanks for the guide references. I still am unable to find it. It may be that the administrator of this server hid that configuration somewhere in an envar or path that I don't have access to.